# Pattern matching of `space` in mathematical expressions

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, expression, mathematical-expressions

I want a pattern which can match both of these expressions:

```
expr1 = `a + b` 
expr1 = `a+b`
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: I want to know the pattern in python.

Comment: I know the pattern for both the expressions. I wanted to know if there is a common pattern for both of them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

> `(\w+)\s*(\S)\s*(\w+)`

first hit gets you the first variable (a), second hit gets you the operand (+) and third hit gets you the second variable (b)
Works also for python
Edit:
resowing the backticks and here's a regex checker for you: 
https://regex101.com/r/Hy1vSl/1